# Extract normalised Eigenvectors in R

Tags: r

I have got the following code:

```
test <- ca.jo(x, type='trace', ecdet='const', K=2)
```

When I am writing summary(test) there occurs:

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

```
              gld.l2     gdx.l2
    gld.l2  1.000000  1.0000000
    gdx.l2 -1.488325 -0.1993057
```

How can I call these normalized Eigenvectors?

When I am writing

```
slot(test, "Vorg")
```

I only get the following data

```
              gld.l2       gdx.l2
    gld.l2 -0.01346063 -0.012380092
    gdx.l2  0.02003378  0.002467422
```

but I want to call the normalized ones.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer a bit? Some reproducible data? What packages you're using? Maybe add some more tags. Right now this question is very localized. Broadening it might help others later find this topic. Also the title is somewhat uninformative. Can you make it reflect the question being asked?

Comment: normalizedEigenvectors = test@V[,1]

Answer (score 3):

```
data(denmark)
sjd <- denmark[, c("LRM", "LRY", "IBO", "IDE")]
sjd.vecm <- ca.jo(sjd, ecdet = "const", type="eigen", K=2, spec="longrun",
                  season=4)
sm <- summary(sjd.vecm)
sm@V
            LRM.l2     LRY.l2     IBO.l2     IDE.l2   constant
LRM.l2    1.000000  1.0000000  1.0000000   1.000000  1.0000000
LRY.l2   -1.032949 -1.3681031 -3.2266580  -1.883625 -0.6336946
IBO.l2    5.206919  0.2429825  0.5382847  24.399487  1.6965828
IDE.l2   -4.215879  6.8411103 -5.6473903 -14.298037 -1.8951589
constant -6.059932 -4.2708474  7.8963696  -2.263224 -8.0330127
```

You might want to check `str(sm)` for more.